# How to bind by name in Oracle PRO*C

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, select, binding

I got a query with bind variables where the same bind variable shows up more than once, for example:

```
select *
  from some_table
  where param1 = :parm1 and
        applied_date = (select min(applied_date)
                          from some_table
                          where param1 = :parm1)
```

When I run this query in sqlplus Oracle appears to be binding by name. I.e. recognizes that the first and the second occurrence of parm1 is the same parameter and prompts me for the value of parm1 only once.
However, when in my C++ program I describe the bind variables into the bind descriptor, it always bind by position.

```
EXEC SQL DESCRIBE BIND VARIABLES FOR my_stmt INTO myBindDesc
```

The value of myBindDesc->F is 2 not 1, and the query won't execute properly until I populate 
both of them, even though it's the same value.
My question is: is there a way to bind by name in PRO*C?

Comment: Hmm... looks like a possible solution might be to use dbms_sql.bind_variable(). Might be a little slower than using the bind descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure the cause of this problem, but you can rewrite the query to use only the :VAR only once in several ways. I hope this can help you -- if not understand, at least solve your problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table tout
JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(param1) AS "param1_min", MIN(applied_date) AS "applied_date_min"
    FROM some_table
    WHERE param1 = :parm1
) taux ON (1=1
AND tout.param1 = taux.param1_min
AND tout.applied_date = taux.applied_date_min
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far. I just re-phrased the question making it clear that the issue is about binding by position vs binding by name. Btw. unfortunately re-writing the query is not an option.